# JavaScript: Carrying Time Variable Across Multiple Functions

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the time time difference between when a function executes, inside a second function.

However I'm note sure what the best way of doing it is. I was considering a global variable, however I'm not sure how that would work considering the variable needed in the second function is the time the first function executed.

Here's my code:

```
var d = new Date(); 

function myFunction(A) {
   // execute function A
   var functionAExecuted = d.getMilliseconds();

}

function myFunction(B) {
   // Execute function B
   var functionBExecuted = d.getMilliseconds();
   var diff = functionAExecuted - functionBExecuted;

   if (diff > 3000) {
   //do something
   }


}
```

It won't execute because `functionAExecuted` won't carry to the second function. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Besides the argument of what will be the best way to do this, as a sidenote `functionAExecuted` will not carry to the second function because of the scope you are defining it in. You can define `functionAExecuted` in the same scope that you have defined `d`, and then set value to it in `myFunction(A)`, so when `myFunction(B)` executes `functionAExecuted` will be available to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple things going on here:

1. For starters, you are using the same `Date` object to measure the start times for each function. The problem with this is that a `Date` object represents a fixed state, namely the exact moment in time when it was instantiated. As a result two separate calls to `getMilliseconds()` will return the same value, regardless of when they are called
2. Your two functions are attempting to access each others' local variables, which, as I'm sure you know, is impossible unless they pass them to each other as arguments.
3. You are redefining your `myFunction` before you actually run `myFunction(A)`. This due to the fact that JavaScript named function **declarations** are hoisted (along with their definitions) to the top of the enclosing context, meaning that the functionality of `myFunction(A)` will always be replaced by that of `myFunction(B)` before you have the chance to call either function. I would advise you to name each function separately and *then* conduct your test.

   - for more information on function hoisting, check out this excellent summary: [Variable and Function hoisting](http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting)

As an alternative, consider renaming your functions and using the outer scope to hold the two times and calculate the difference after the fact:

```
var times = {};

function myFunctionA(a) {
  times.functionA = new Date();
  // do something
}

function myFunctionB(b) {
  times.functionB = new Date();

  var diff = times.functionB.getMilliseconds() - times.functionA.getMilliseconds();

  if (diff > 3000) {
    //do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer! The outer scope works really well. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

I would store the first value in a form, then retrieve it in the second function:

```
var d = new Date(); 

function myFunction(A) {
   var functionAExecuted = d.getMilliseconds();
   // do something
   document.forms.myForm.timeStorageFunctionA.value = functionAExecuted;
}
```

Now d.getMilliseconds() is accessible:

```
function myFunction(B) {
    var functionBExecuted = new Date().getMilliseconds();
    var functionAExecuted = document.forms.myForm.timeStorageFunctionA.value;
    var diff = functionAExecuted - functionBExecuted;

    if (diff > 3000) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that if function B is the second function called, you will want diff = B - A, or if you keep the code as is, you will need the absolute value of diff